# displaying data from database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to perform a sql query to list the customer information on my website for which ever customer is logged in.

this is the code

```
<?php
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['who'];
  require_once('dbconn.php');
  $sql = "select fname,lname,email,address,suburb,state,postcode,phone from customer where id = '$user' ";
        $rs = $dbConn->query($sql);

?>

<h3> Your Current Details: </h3>
    <p><strong>first name:</strong> <?php  while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['fname'] ;}
?></p>
    <p><strong>last name:</strong> <?php while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['lname'] ;} ?></p>
    <p><strong>email:</strong> <?php while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['email'] ;} ?></p>
    <p><strong>post code:</strong> <?php while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['postcode'] ;}?></p>
    <p><strong>state:</strong> <?php while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['state'] ;} ?></p>
    </div>
```

the session for the user occurs on my login page which is successful
However it is only displaying the first name of the customer and that is it.

Comment: Try to print the data using print_r() and check. Kindly note your are using while loop for every column which not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to  loop over the result set multiple times when you only need to do so once. Move the `while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())` outside the display code:

```
<h3> Your Current Details: </h3>
<?php while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <p><strong>first name:</strong> <?php echo $row['fname']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>last name:</strong> <?php echo $row['lname']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>email:</strong> <?php echo $row['email']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>post code:</strong> <?php echo $row['postcode']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>state:</strong> <?php echo $row['state']; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your dbConn class could be closing the connection in $rs->fetch_assoc() thus having no database data the next few time you attempt to use it. Without that code it's hard to give you quality feedback.

However, @Mehedi Hasan Siam has a great solution but be mindful that there is a small typo in their response, change "mysqli_fdetch_assoc" to "mysqli_fetch_assoc"

See W3Schools for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp